# How to make a specific cell in Janus GridEx to be not editable

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, janus, gridex

In my VB.net application I have a Janus GridEx (v.3).

By default, each cell of each row is editable. But in certain conditions, I want **a specific cell** to be set to `ReadOnly` (or someting that unset the edit mode for this cell) during `RowLoadEvent`.

I know how to make an entire column not selectable (and how to get a specific cell) with :

```
e.Row.Cells("IndiceNew").Column.Selectable = False
```

But the only properties I can set are related to format (image, colors...).
Any tips ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Janus GridEx column readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225087/how-to-make-a-janus-gridex-column-readonly)

Comment: @preciousbetine Nope, as I said, i want to set only one specific **cell** to be not editable. That question is about making an entire column not editable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a way to do it. So here is what I did if it may help someone facing the same problem.

Instead of doing at `LoadRowEvent` time, I just cancel edit event during `EditingCellEvent` with something like :

```
Dim myDataSetRow As myDataSet.DataSetRow
myDataSetRow = CType(myGrid.GetRow().DataRow, DataRowView).Row

If Not myDataSetRow.IsIndiceModifiable Then 'the condition to check
    e.Cancel = True 'cancel edition
End If
```

Hope it can help someone in the future.